# Combined Center of gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, mass

If I have two masses connected together, it's pretty simple to calculate the CoG of the system.
But if the two masses are connected with a hinge?
My question arrives from the motorcycle world. I'm a dirt biker and, when I'm cornering, I don't touch the seat but I have to put all my body weight on the footpeg. I always drive in this way (like every dirt biker and, I think every street motorcyclist), because ever since I was a child they taught me to do it in this way, because you use your legs like one more damper, and because you lower the Cog (in the footpeg and not in the seat) and the bike will be easier to be controlled.
But now I'm thinking... you lower your CoG? Is it true?

Comment: That is because you have to overcome the centrifugal force

Answer (score 2):

The CoG almost certainly goes up when your rear end rises from the seat. The reason it is propably an advantageous posture is that the 'unsprung' mass goes down (just the bike) and you have more ability to control that mass by shifting weight and torque from your body between the two footpegs.  Also your comment about being able to damp unwanted motion is very relevant.  BTW this answer is coming from someone has never ridden a motorcycle.